# Burninate the [service-rec] tag and delete its questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [service-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/service-rec) tag, aside from likely being a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), has 22 of its 23 questions closed for being off-topic and not constructive.

As I don't believe that this tag, or its questions for that matter, belong on Super User, I'd love to see questions tagged with [service-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/service-rec) deleted and the tag itself burninated.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all gone now.

The tag will disappear after a day so long as a new question isn't going to drink its own bowl of draino by tagging itself with the tag itself.